# Using navigation controllers within a tabbar application.

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have created a tabbar application that contains several table view each with a navigation controller embedded. Not sure if im using navigation controllers in the wrong context and was wondering if someone could help me understand.

I have taken a screen shot [Here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s226/sh/367e4306-6212-4653-8d01-2f5314665f13/9cd01205481af9cb0a6c94d7a89716ea)

The red arrows show the embedded navigation controllers. Should I have just one navigation controller at the green arrow or am I correct in using multiple navigation controllers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct.

A navigation controller represents a linear movement through your app. i.e. it can only take one specific path through your app forwards and backwards.

With a tab bar controller you want a navigation controller for each tab because you've got a multi-dimensional navigation structure. You can not only move linearly from "start to end" but you can also jump between those navigation lines.

I hope that makes sense, but yes... you can (and should) use navigation controllers as many times as you have a navigation "path" to present to the user.